# Django compressor fails to find any `compress` tags

Tags: python, django, django-compressor

I am trying to implement `django-compressor` into my project. Doing `$ python manage.py compress` works with the following setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load compress %}
    {% compress js %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/lodash.compat.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/jquery.color.js"></script>
    {% endcompress %}
```

This works:

```
Compressing... done
Compressed 2 block(s) from 21 template(s).
```

However, if I add in another `templatetag` **anywhere** in that file, it throws an error:

```
{% load extras %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load compress %}
    {% compress js %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/lodash.compat.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/jquery.color.js"></script>
    {% endcompress %}
```

This is the error:

```
$ python manage.py compress
...
compressor.exceptions.OfflineGenerationError: No 'compress' template tags found in templates.Try running compress command with --follow-links and/or--extension=EXTENSIONS
```

Why is this error occurring? The `extras` tag templatetags has absolutely nothing to do with django-compress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code of [`django-compressor (compress.py:189-204)`](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/blob/487ea6dddf80269d919dd5df6ea8323c9475d54e/compressor/management/commands/compress.py#L189-L204), such `OfflineGenerationError` occur when there is a syntax error in one of your template. To debug this error, you can change the `verbosity > 0` so it will print the template name that cause the error.

Hope this can help you to debug the syntax error. 
The last resort of debugging is to use pdb into the [`compress.py:169`](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/blob/487ea6dddf80269d919dd5df6ea8323c9475d54e/compressor/management/commands/compress.py#L169) and check why the `compressor_nodes` is empty. 
`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`